# How can I create a burger menu with tkinter and Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I create a burger menu on the right corner of my Tkinter application window similar to the menu we see on web/phone applications?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd suggest using a `ttk.Button()` with an image for the hamburger, styled as you like.

Comment: I am working with the standard Menu() bar at the top of the window. I am looking for suggestions.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do what you want with the `Menu()` class